# Does Apache Spark really need to ship the functions(code)?

Tags: apache-spark

Does Apache Spark really need to ship the functions(code)? If so, why? Given that there is a jar in all master and worker machines.

For Example:

Lets take the following code

```
/* GenerateNames.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.util.Random

object GenerateNames {
    val outputDir = "/home/jung/sparkapp/output/part"
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GenerateNames")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    for (partition <- 0 to 3) {
        val data = Seq.fill(1000000)(Random.alphanumeric.take(5).mkString)
        sc.parallelize(data, 1).saveAsTextFile(outputDir + "_" + partition)
    }
  }
}
```

Now say I package this into `sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar` and submit my application the following way.

```
 /home/jung/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit \
 --class GenerateNames /home/jung/sparkapp/target/scala-2.11/sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar
```

Now I can see the jar file `sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar` in all worker machines under `$SPARK_HOME/work/app-20180906084236-0000/0/sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar`

And since `sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar` exists in all worker machines under `$SPARK_HOME/work/app-20180906084236-0000/0` what is the reason to ship code at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> Given that there is a jar in all master and worker machines

Not necessarily. For example, in YARN, Kubernetes, or Mesos master modes, the Spark core JARs are typically only available in a shared filesystem, where they are later downloaded and cached for your executing code.

Other than that, yes, it must ship your code, which uses additional functions that are not available by the core Spark APIs, however, your code doesn't need to include Spark itself (i.e. You use provided scope in Maven)

> I can see the jar file sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar in all worker machines

**Exactly** - your code was shipped! Because it needs to be ran by other machines in the Spark cluster, and it could be any machine; that's not something you can choose

Comment: can you give an example of what part of the code does spark really ship?

Comment: "For example, in YARN, Kubernetes, or Mesos master modes, the Spark core JARs are typically only available in a shared filesystem, where they are later downloaded and cached for your executing code." This also tells me master and workers have a way to access the same Jar one way or other and if so I have the same question as above.

Comment: If you look at the Javadoc/Scala/Python classes of Spark, all those are included, which also includes core Scala, and some other JVM libraries

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me, sorry. You need the Spark code to run anything. Otherwise, you get "class not found". If you start up a new Spark cluster, it's not a requirement to copy around the libraries yourself, that's what my first statement about caching was trying to say

Comment: It's almost like running Docker in any scheduler - do you really have to pull the images on every machine? Yes, you do, but not if they've already been pulled.

Comment: Hard to understand this without a small snippet of code. And I am really trying to understand what code does spark really ship? When I write code using spark api and submit my application jar using spark-submit. spark master and worker machines have a way to access my application jar. if so, I am still not seeing the reason to ship code?

Comment: Let say my application.jar has something like `df.map(row -> myfunc(row))` what part of it gets shipped here? given that my application.jar is somehow available or accessible by both master and worker machines.

Comment: Depends on your Spark master settings. If cluster mode, all of it is shipped. if client mode, only the parts that actually need ran on remote machines outside of your current driver

Comment: In particular, it needs to know what `df` and `myfunc` are, and how to recompute them in the event of a failure, for example, and therefore, they need to be serializable types

Comment: well my understanding was that `df` and `myfunc` are already available in the my application.jar that say master and worker machines already cached it..so stil trying to understand the reason for shipment?

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you're trying to ask. Your variables are not part of the JAR. Nothing in your code is pre-computed. Your code is just an instruction set for defining variables and actions on them...

Comment: I thought with SBT assembly or package via IntelliJ all was in the uberJAR? @cricket_007

Comment: @theblue It's still just compiled classes, not actual data. Feel free to give own answer if you think I'm wrong

Comment: @cricket_007  May be we are talking at cross purposes, but i think on certain aspects you outclass me. So I will read again very carefully tonight. May be I have lost the gist of the original question.